# The American accents/The British accents VS American accents/British accents

Tags: phrase-usage, articles, definite-article, phrase-choice

Do you think in the sentence below we should use the definite article or not before the highlighted phrases?

- I like (the) **British accents** better than (the) **American accents**.

I have seen both of the occasions when the definite article was used and it wasn't in sentences like this in which you talk about the accents in a region/country generally. Are both of the versions with or without the definite article correct?

Comment: Bloody hell, Deputy Dawg! Now me girl's me wife! (etc).

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Sorry?

Comment: Why use an article? When you say you have seen it, I wonder, you have seen that exact usage repeatedly? I like British sports' writers better than American sports' writers. Generalities do not require "the".

Answer (score 1):

We use the definite article when something is *specific*. It can be a single thing in isolation or a *group/collection* of things that is easily identified.

There are many regional accents in both American and British English. If you were referring to *all* of them, there would be no need for an article, definite or otherwise, because "I like American accents" would sufficiently convey that you liked them all. So, if the purpose of your example is to simply compare *all* accents, there is no need for an article. The pluralisation of 'accents' makes it clear you are acknowledging there are many, so all you need to say is:

> I like British accents better than American accents.

"I like *the* British (or American) accents" in isolation seems wrong, but in a context where it is clear that you are referring to a *specific set of accents*, it could be ok. For example, if you watched a movie in which there were a limited number of identifiable accents, you could say "I liked *the American accents* in that movie".

Comment: Thanks. People tend to say “the American accent” or “the British accent”, “the Australian accent” etc. when they also talk generally about a British accent or an American accent etc. in situations when they are not talking about a specific person’s accent. They say, “He hates hearing the British accent” instead of “He hates hearing British accent”. They can also say, “He hates hearing the British accents” too. Don’t you see or hear this usage?

Comment: Yes, we say _the British accent_ when speaking of it as though it were a single accent, but _British accents_ when referring to the many accents which actually exist in the British Isles.

Comment: @KateBunting I see. Thanks.

Comment: The British accent in that sense is using the to refer to a general idea. "The poodle is an intelligent dog". But you can't use that everywhere and all the time.

Comment: @Lambie No, that is not a comparable example. There is only one pure breed of dog that can be called 'the poodle'. But there are around 40 different dialects spoken in Britain, so there is no one 'British accent'.

Comment: "The poodle is a very intelligent breed" uses the article just like: "The British accent is hard to imitate". In English, the other way to state a general thing like those two things is to use the plural: Poodles and British accents. The "the" is less used in informal English, of any variety.

Comment: @Lambie But there isn't just one British accent, so "**the** British accent", said as a generalisation, would be incorrect. Actors would say "I can do **a** British accent". The only context where you could say "*the* British accent" would be if you were referring to a specific accent within a limited context. For example, if you watched a film set entirely in Liverpool, you could say "the British accent in that film was hard to understand".

Comment: Yes and no. It depends. An acting class coach might say: The British accent is hard to do on the first try. Typically, in language learning, one refers to an American accent or a British accent. Yes, but nothing is stopping: The British accent sounds difficult to me. Accents are only accents with an s within a language group if the speaker knows it. One could say, it's a matter for specialists.

Comment: @Lambie If a voice coach said that there was only one British accent I would seriously question their credentials.

Comment: The British accent is one of the most recognizable and distinctive accents in the English language. https://magoosh.com/english-speaking/learn-how-to-speak-with-a-british-accent/

Comment: @lambie the same page you link to also says "British accents" and "a British accent". It's completely inconsistent and I don't trust it as a source.

Comment: @Astralbee: whether or not it is  reliable as a source is an entirely different question from whether it is using English constructions in a natural way. In several of your comments you seem to be confounding accuracy with grammaticality.